# Foster momma cat causing trouble, how to solve it?

Tags: cats, behavior, aggression, breeding, feral

One month ago we rescued a pregnant cat from a risky area. People who knew her there told us she already got pregnant about 3 times before, but they never saw the kitens and they suspected someone killed her previous litters. So we took her in and two weeks later she had the kittens.

She was a little aggressive towards the humans of the house when pregnant but became much calmer and even friendly after the birth, rubbing against us, meowing softly when she saw us, showing her belly. She let us handle the kittens with no problem.

But now she's attacking the other cats in the house, unprovoked and without warning. Yesterday she attacked one of our fosters from behind, without hissing or anything, she just lashed out on him.

I feel like locking her up with her kitties won't do a lot of good in the long run, besides, she hates being locked up and she's always asking for attention and head rubs.

I feel like she's bored out of her mind and has no escape for her energy, but I've tried playing with her with a toy stick (those with feathers in one end), and she absolutely ignored the toy.

How can I help her calm down with the other cats and also let out some steam?

She's about 3 years old, healthy, fluffy, and has 5 kittens.

Comment: dont give up playing whith your cat(i have some experience in trying to play whit a feral cat)some feral or partly feral cats dont understand that you are trying to play whith them,so what to do is get a laser and use this to play whith the cat this aktually works.

Comment: @trond hansen, thank you. I'll try the laser. She really needs some movement.

Comment: We currently have a temporary visitor (stray cat waiting to be adopted), and our cats don't like him (though they only hiss at him, they don't attack him). We do notice that they are somewhat more accepting of him after we've been giving them treats (= being fed from the same hand). I think this helps paint the other cat as an equal, as they're almost literally "breaking bread" with him. Communal feeding/treat times might help in humanizing (felinizing?) the cats to each other.